Rails named yield won't work unless I add another non-named yield above
I have a partial that I am trying to render content inside of
<!-- app/views/shared/_yes_no_toggle.html.erb -->
<div data-controller="yes-no-toggle">
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <button type="button" data-action="click->yes-no-toggle#onYes" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-l rounded-r-none text-xs" aria-labelledby="yes-no-label">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" data-action="click->yes-no-toggle#onNo" class="bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-r rounded-l-none text-xs" aria-labelledby="yes-no-label">No</button>
    <label class="ms-2" id="yes-no-label">Include Core Funded Services?</label>
  </div>

  <div data-target="yes-no-toggle.yesView" class="mt-4 hidden">
    <%= yield :yes_content %>
  </div>
  <div data-target="yes-no-toggle.noView" class="mt-4 hidden">
    <%= yield :no_content %>
  </div>
</div>

However, when I try to render this view within another rendered view, the named <%= yield :yes_content %> won't work unless I add another yield tag on top:
<!-- app/views/shared/_yes_no_toggle.html.erb -->
...
  <div data-target="yes-no-toggle.yesView" class="mt-4 hidden">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= yield :yes_content %>
  </div>
  <div data-target="yes-no-toggle.noView" class="mt-4 hidden">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= yield :no_content %>
  </div>
...

This is being called inside another partial
<!-- app/views/shared/example/_form.html.erb -->
<%= render 'shared/yes_no_toggle' do %>
  <% content_for :yes_content do %>
    <span>Hello World</span>
  <% end %>

  <% content_for :no_content do %>
    <span>Goodbye World</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

Can someone help me understand what's happening here? I have gone through the documentation to understand how it may be working but I'm a bit stumped. I've tried adding the content_for below the proposed render but no luck.

Without plain yield the block that you pass to render 'shared/yes_no_toggle' is never executed which means content_for is never populated with anything.
The actual render is a lot more complicated, this is as simple as I could make it in terms of actual logic underneath:
def content_for name
  @content_for ||= {}
  if block_given?
    @content_for[name] = yield
  else
    @content_for[name]
  end
end

def render template
  # calls _yes_no_toggle method
  send(template) do |content|
    if content
      content_for(content)
    else
      yield if block_given?          # here <---------------.
    end                              #                      |
  end                                #                      |
end                                  #                      |
                                     #                      |
def _yes_no_toggle                   #                      |
  # NOTE: without yielding >-------------.                  |
  # yield                            #   |                  |
                                     #   |                  |
  "<div>" +                          #   |                  |
    yield(:yes_content).to_s +       #   |                  |
    yield(:no_content).to_s +        #   |                  |
  "</div>"                           #   |                  |
end                                  #   |                  |
                                     #   |                  |
def _form                            #   |                  |
  render :_yes_no_toggle do          # <-' this block       |
    content_for :yes_content do      #     is never called -'
      "<span>Hello World</span>"     #
    end                              #
    content_for :no_content do       #
      "<span>Goodbye World</span>"   #
    end                              #
  end
end

# without yield
_form
#=> "<div></div>"

# with yield
_form
#=> "<div><span>Hello World</span><span>Goodbye World</span></div>"

Also, remember that yield(:yes_content) is the same as content_for(:yes_content) maybe that will clear up confusion with plain yield.

That actually makes a lot of sense. So yield is basically executing the block of code that's inside the partial, making the making the named yields available on subsequent calls. Is there a reason these aren't executed by default?

@Brandyn they are executed it's just corresponding content_for is empty. and executing the block given to render automatically doesn't make sense, since it is up to you to decide where you want to place that content, which you do by calling yield. you can also put content_for :yes_content do ... blocks above the render  call and it should work. content_for is a global state, it is not per render call. for this kind of composition i'd use something else https://github.com/viewcomponent/view_component or https://github.com/bullet-train-co/nice_partials
